# Equivalent statement of AC or not?

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice

Here's a corollary of AC stating that: if there exists an onto mapping $f:A\to B$, then there exists a 1-1 mapping $g:B\to A$. What I'm confused about is that whether or not  AC can be derived from this proposition, in return? I have tried but haven't found a proof.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: see this answer https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/108810/does-a-injective-function-f-a-to-b-and-surjective-function-g-a-to-b-impl

Comment: I wrote about this extensively.

Comment: http://karagila.org/2014/on-the-partition-principle/#:~:text=The%20Partition%20Principle%20%28PP%29%20is%20the%20principle%20stating,B%20parts%2C%20we%20could%20only%20decrease%20the%20cardinality.

Comment: I think the answer can be found here that the statement might be a weakening of AC.

Comment: The answer is that it is an open problem.