# existence of a linear isomorphism.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $f:V \rightarrow W$ be an onto linear map and $g:W \rightarrow V$ be an onto linear map. Does there exist a linear isomorphism from $V \rightarrow W$.
i am stuck on the case when $V$ and $W$ are infinite-dimensional.

Please help.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this requires the axiom of choice; perhaps one of our resident set theorists will come along and explain the details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question is yes. Let $\dim V=\lambda$ and $\dim W=\kappa$. Fix a basis $B$ for $f$. Since $f(B)$ spans $W$ there exists a a surjection of $B$ onto a basis for $W$. Thus, $\lambda\geqslant \kappa$. Using the exact same idea in reverse says that $\kappa\geqslant\lambda$. It then follows from the [Schroeder-Bernstein theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%E2%80%93Bernstein%E2%80%93Schroeder_theorem) that $\lambda=\kappa$. Thus, $V$ and $W$ have the same dimension and so are isomorphic.

Comment: Cantor-Schroeder-Bernstein is for injections, not surjections. [See this math.SE thread](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/176972/264).

Comment: @ZevChonoles The axiom of choice implies that if there is a surjection $X\to Y$ there is an injection $Y\to X$.

Comment: Agreed, but my point was only that you are using the axiom of choice here, whereas the theorem itself does not.

Comment: @ZevChonoles Good thing I'm not a logician.

Comment: Haha, okay :) +1 from me

Comment: The existence of a basis already requires the A of C, no?

Comment: @GerryMyerson True, true. This is why I don't think about the AC--I undoubtedly used it at least three times typing this response.