# Structures that are reciprocally homomorphic images but are not isomorphic

Tags: abstract-algebra, model-theory, universal-algebra

Consider two algebras $\mathscr{A}=\langle A,O_i\rangle$ and $\mathscr{B}=\langle B,P_i\rangle$ with the same type. Suppose that there is a homomorphism from $A$ onto $B$, and a homomorphism from $B$ onto $A$. Clearly (edit: [not really](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/176972/is-there-a-cantor-schroder-bernstein-statement-about-surjective-maps)), $|A|=|B|$. It is easy to prove that if the algebras are finite, they must be isomorphic, but can we conclude the same thing for infinite algebras? I can find a counterexample for the same question about *relational structures* (sets equipped with relations) but my counterexample uses a one-many relation (the structures are $\big\langle\mathbb{N},\{\langle1,1\rangle,\langle1,2\rangle\}\big\rangle$ and $\big\langle\mathbb{N},\{\langle1,1\rangle\}\big\rangle$).

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/176972/is-there-a-cantor-schroder-bernstein-statement-about-surjective-maps

Comment: @Eran, not really.

Comment: It certainly doesn't answer your question, but it does explain that your use of "Clearly" requires the assumption of some form of choice.

Comment: @Eran Oh! I didn't pay attention to that. Thanks!

Comment: @Navid How do you define a homomorphism of relational structures $(A, R)$ and $(B, S)$? According to [this source](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/computer-science/relational-structure), $\phi: A\to B$ is a homomorphism if $(a,b) \in R \iff (\phi(a), \phi(b)) \in S$ (in case $R$ and $S$ are binary relations). But then what are your homomorphisms in your example? Or do you only require $(a, b)\in R \implies (\phi(a), \phi(b)) \in S$? In that case $\phi(x) = \max\{1, x-1\}$ and $\psi(x)=x$ would work... But then what's stopping $\psi:B\to A$ from being an isomorphism?

Comment: @Milten I'm defining homomorphisms with a one-direction if, and isomorphisms as injective onto homomorphisms.

Comment: @Navid Ah, the right definition should be that the map and its inverse should both be homomorphisms (as in any category). As you wrote it, isomorphic-ness wouldn't be an equivalence relation. And with this your example works again 

Comment: @Mitten I suppose this is the definition they use in universal algebra. I'm reading Dunn and Hardegree.

Comment: @Milten Looking more closely it seems to be a confusion in the book.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Consider the abelian groups  $G = \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}\oplus \dots$ (countably many copies) and $H = \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}\oplus \dots$ (countably many copies).

There is a surjective homomorphism $G\to H$ which is the quotient map $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ on the first component and the identity on all other components: $(a_1,a_2,a_3,\dots)\mapsto (\overline{a}_1,a_2,a_3,\dots)$ where $\overline{a}_1$ is the residue of $a_1$ mod $2$.

There is also a surjective homomorphism $H\to G$ which projects out the first component:  $(a_1,a_2,a_3,\dots)\mapsto (a_2,a_3,a_4,\dots)$.

But these groups are not isomorphic. Note that the element $(1,0,0,\dots)$ in $H$ has order $2$ but is not divisible by $2$. On the other hand, every element of order $2$ in $G$ is divisible by $2$, since it has a $0$ or a $2$ in each component.

Comment: Why the second map is surjective though? We have $(3, 0, 0, \ldots )$ in $G$ which the map doesn't give.

Comment: $(3,0,0,\dots)$ is the image of $(0,3,0,0,\dots)$. @Navid

Answer (score 4):

Let $G$ be an infinite group and let $H$ be a nontrivial proper subgroup. Let $A$ be the $G$-set that has countably infinitely many singleton orbits and countably infinitely many regular orbits (i.e., orbits isomorphic to ${}_GG$).  Now let $B$ be constructed exactly like $A$, but include one more orbit isomorphic to ${}_G(G/H)$. $A$ is not isomorphic to $B$, since $B$ contains a point whose stabilizer is $H$ and $A$ does not. But there is a homomorphism of $A$ onto $B$ that collapses one regular orbit to ${}_G(G/H)$, and there is a homomorphism of $B$ onto $A$ that collapses the orbit ${}_G(G/H)$ onto a singleton.

Comment: I'll mention for other readers that this is very similar to and generalizes Alex Kruckman's example if we set $G=\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z$ and $H=2G$. The main difference being that Alex Kruckman makes homomorphisms of groups whereas Keith Kearnes makes homomorphisms of $G$-sets (but I'm pretty sure the constructions are equivalent). Also Alex doesn't have the singleton orbits.

Comment: KeithKearnes; Is it necessary for $G$ to be infinite?

Comment: It is not necessary for $G$ to be infinite. I picked it that way to ensure that it had a nontrivial proper subgroup, but for this you only need that $|G|$ is not prime.