# Analog of Cantor-Schroder-Bernstein theorem for surjective homomorphisms between groups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

I'm thinking of the following problem: If we have two groups $G$ and $H$, with **surjective** homomorphisms $\psi:G\to H$ and $\phi:H \to G$, is it possible to prove that $G$ and $H$ are isomorphic? Or could we construct a counterexample?

$G$ and $H$ must have the same cardinality (see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/176972/is-there-a-cantor-schroder-bernstein-statement-about-surjective-maps)), but I don't know that whether they are necessarily isomorphic.

I know that the Cantor-Schroder-Bernstein theorem doesn't hold for groups (see [here](https://scholarworks.umt.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1327&context=tme)), but I'm wondering that whether the situation would be different for surjective homomorphisms.

Comment: No. For example, it fails for the Baumslag-Solitar BS(4, 6) group; see https://arxiv.org/pdf/1308.5122.pdf . (The Baumslag-Solitar groups are generally great examples for this sort of bad behavior.)

Comment: @anomaly But what are the non-isomorphic groups $G$ and $H$ in this example?

Comment: Take $G = BS(4, 6)$. For $H$, there's a construction outlined in the paper that gives an finite family of groups; see Cor. 6.8.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, it is not true. We can, for example, take $G = \prod_{\mathbb{N}} S_3$ to be the product of countably many copies of $S_3$, and take $H = G \times C_2$. $G$ and $H$ are not isomorphic because $G$ has trivial center but $H$ has nontrivial center. But there is a surjection $G \to H$ given by mapping the first copy of $S_3$ to $C_2$ via the sign homomorphism and then mapping the $n^{th}$ copy of $S_3$ to the $(n-1)^{th}$ copy of $S_3$, and there is a surjection $H \to G$ given by quotienting by $C_2$.

This is related to the existence of [non-Hopfian groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopfian_group).

Comment: Very nice! Seems like this construction should work for any non-abelian group $G$ with trivial center which admits a surjection onto some group $A$ with nontrivial center (playing the roles of $S_{3}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ respectively).

Comment: Right. Probably various generalizations are possible too.

Comment: Another (probably standard) example, with abelian groups: use $C_4$ instead of $S_3$. In these examples we also have $G$ embedding into $H$ and $H$ embedding into $G$. Any example where this doesn't happen?

Comment: @spin Something like $F$ and $F\times \mathbb Z$, where $F$ is a countable-rank free group? Maybe $F\times F$ and $F\times \mathbb Z$ means neither is a subgroup of the other.