# Can a surjection and injection exist but not a bijection?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If I there exists an injection $\phi: S_1 \to S_2$ and a surjection $\tau: S_1 \to S_2$, does there necessarily exist a bijection between sets $S_1$ and $S_2$?

I'd like this to be true, but I don't see a way to construct a bijection directly from $\phi$ and $\tau$.

Comment: Depends of AC..

Comment: @hchau, could you tell us the level that you're learning at? Depending on if you're learning elementary discrete maths, or axiomatic set theory, it can make a big difference to what form your answer takes.

Comment: Oh, so I haven't actually taken an undergraduate set theory course yet, but this question just popped into my mind, so I thought I'd ask it here.

Comment: I have actually answered this question at least once on this site (and I believe that it was twice or thrice).

Comment: Yes, I have found four copies: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/46168/proof-of-a-cantor-bernstein-like-theorem and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/108810/does-a-injective-function-f-a-to-b-and-surjective-function-g-a-to-b-impl/ and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/176972/is-there-a-cantor-schroder-bernstein-statement-about-surjective-maps/ and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/220617/sur-in-bijections-and-cardinality/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The statement that if there is a surjection from $A$ to $B$, then there is an injection from $B$ to $A$ is known as the *Partition principle*. It is a consequence of the axiom of choice, and it’s not known whether it is equivalent to the axiom of choice. Given the partition principle, the existence of both an injection and a surjection from $A$ to $B$ implies the existence of injections from $A$ to $B$ and $B$ to $A$, and the [Schröder-Bernstein theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%E2%80%93Bernstein%E2%80%93Schroeder_theorem) then implies that there is a bijection from $A$ to $B$.

Answer (score 4):

[Cantor-Bernstein-Schroeder Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%E2%80%93Bernstein%E2%80%93Schroeder_theorem)

And the fact that, if there exists a surjection from A to B, then there exists an injection from B to A.

Comment: Assuming the axiom of choice. Which really should be mentioned in this case, since the Schröder-Bernstein theorem itself does **not** require AC.

Comment: Strictly speaking, a surjection from A to B only implies an injection from B to A if you have some form of the axiom of choice at your disposal.