# When do surjections split in ZF? Two surjections imply bijection?

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice, axioms

We have that the Axiom of Choice is equivalent to the principle that *every* surjection has a right inverse. However, without the Axiom of Choice we can determine for some $X$ that $X\succeq Y\implies Y\preceq X$. Some immediate instances are when $X$ is finite (by the Principle of Finite Choice) and even when $X$ is countable (put in bijection with $\mathbb{N}$ and then choose the least element of the preimages).

I was wondering for what other $X$ does this hold? Clearly it holds for well-orderable sets, but does the principle extend to sets like $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ or any other set that ZF can 'sanely' construct (as in be created without Choice)?

That is my first question. My second question is whether the following principle is equivalent to the Axiom of Choice:
$$X\succeq Y\wedge Y\succeq X\implies X\simeq Y$$
This principle somewhat mirrors Schroeder-Bernstein, and can be derived with the Axiom of Choice; however, I've never seen a proof (not even a remark) that it is equivalent to or weaker than Choice.

These questions are just out of personal curiosity.

Notation: $X\succeq Y$ means $X$ surjects onto $Y$, and $Y\preceq X$ means $Y$ injects into $X$.

Comment: (1) It's the most horrible thing in the world to use the same symbol, just backwards, for two different relations. (2) This relation is often denoted by $\leq^*$, where $\leq$ is the injection-based relation. (3) I've personally written at least two answers on this question before. (4) The Cantor-Bernstein like is called "Dual Cantor-[Schroder]-Bernstein" and it is an open problem whether or not it is equivalent to $\sf AC$, but we know it is not provable without at least some fragment of choice. I will, however, add an answer because not everything is covered by previous threads.

Comment: I apologize for the notation, but I must say that I despise the absolute value bars and attaching asterisks to symbols. Thank you for naming the principle; I'll search for it. Have you made a remark on my first question elsewhere?

Comment: Meh, probably. But sadly it's become easier to write a block of text than to find it. In each iteration where I answer questions again I try to include information that I don't recall writing before, so it's not a huge loss either way.

Comment: It helps to have a name. Here's a link for future ponderers: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/38771/dual-schroeder-bernstein-theorem

Comment: I've added a long list of links. Including this one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all notation. Using the same symbol in reverse for different things is horrible. Let's use the usual notation. $X\leq Y$ means there is an injection from $X$ into $Y$, $X\leq^* Y$ means that either $X$ is empty, or there is a surjection from $Y$ onto $X$, and we'll keep the $X\simeq Y$ as you did for the existence of a bijection.

In $\sf ZF$ the Cantor-Bernstein theorem holds. We don't need $\sf AC$ to prove: $$X\leq Y\land Y\leq X\iff X\simeq Y.$$

On the other hand, the dual notion for $\leq^*$ is not provable in $\sf ZF$. We call this the Dual Cantor-Bernstein Theorem, and it states the very thing we expect it to, $$X\leq^*Y\land Y\leq^*X\iff X\simeq Y.$$

When this statement is true, for example, then every infinite set has a countably infinite set. Something which is consistently false in $\sf ZF$.

The problem on how much choice it implies, and how much choice is needed to prove it is open. The only thing that was proved, to my knowledge, is that if we make a certain strengthening of this theorem then the axiom of choice holds, but we don't know anything else.

Now, for extending the reversibility of surjections, the answer is that in most cases, you can expect it to fail. For example, It is provable in $\sf ZF$ that $\mathcal P(\omega)$ can be mapped onto $\omega_1$, but there are models where there is no injection back. There is exactly one case that I know of where it is provable to have reversible surjections. The following case.

**Definition.** For an infinite $\aleph$ cardinal $\kappa$ we say that $A$ is **$\kappa$-amorphous** if every subset of $A$ is of size $<\kappa$, or its complement is of cardinality $<\kappa$. We say that $A$ is **strongly** $\kappa$-amorphous if for every $S$, a partition of $A$, the set $\{X\in S\mid |X|>1\}$ has size strictly less than $\kappa$.

**Theorem.** Suppose that $\sf AC_{<\kappa}$ holds, and $A$ is strongly $\kappa$-amorphous then every $f\colon A\to B$ which is surjective can be reversed.

(Where $\sf AC_{<\kappa}$ is the statement that every family of strictly less than $\kappa$ non-empty sets admits a choice function.)

*Proof.* Left to the interested reader. $\square$

---

**Further reading.**

1. [Is there a Cantor-Schroder-Bernstein statement about surjective maps?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/176972/is-there-a-cantor-schroder-bernstein-statement-about-surjective-maps)
2. [Cantor-Bernstein-like theorem: If $f\colon A\to B$ is injection and $g\colon A\to B$ is surjective, can we prove there is a bijection as well?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/46168/cantor-bernstein-like-theorem-if-f-colon-a-to-b-is-injection-and-g-colon-a-)
3. [Sur- in- bijections and cardinality.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/220617/sur-in-bijections-and-cardinality/)
4. [Does a injective function $f: A \to B$ and surjective function $g : A\to B$ imply a bijective function exists?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/108810/does-a-injective-function-f-a-to-b-and-surjective-function-g-a-to-b-impl/)
5. [Proving existence of a surjection $2^{\aleph_0} \to \aleph_1$ without AC](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/407833/proving-existence-of-a-surjection-2-aleph-0-to-aleph-1-without-ac)
6. [Dual Schroeder-Bernstein theorem](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/38771/dual-schroeder-bernstein-theorem) (MathOverflow)
7. [Half Cantor-Bernstein Without Choice](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/65369/half-cantor-bernstein-without-choice) (MathOverflow)
8. [Does $2^X=2^Y\Rightarrow |X|=|Y|$ imply the axiom of choice?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/81204/does-2x-2y-rightarrow-x-y-imply-the-axiom-of-choice) (MathOverflow)
9. [Uncountable subset with uncountable complement, without the Axiom of Choice](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17432/uncountable-subset-with-uncountable-complement-without-the-axiom-of-choice)
10. [Infinite Set is Disjoint Union of Two Infinite Sets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60281/infinite-set-is-disjoint-union-of-two-infinite-sets)
11. [A question about the Axiom of Choice](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/135945/a-question-about-the-axiom-of-choice/) (MathOverflow)