# Surjective function from a countable set

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, axiom-of-choice

In Lang "Real and Functional analysis" is demonstrated that given a countable set $A$ and a function $f: A \rightarrow B$ which is surjective on $B$, then $B$ is finite or countable.

Proof: Consider $y \in B$ then there exists a non void set $F_y= \{x \in A | f(x)=y \}$, consider one element of the set , say $x_y \in F_y$. Now the assosiation $y \rightarrow x_y$ is injective from $B \rightarrow A$ (the proof of injectivity is easy) then, for the definiton of [countability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countable_set) we have that also $B$ is countable.

My questions are:

- It seems to me that this proof uses the *axiom of choice* to choose the elements in the family $F_y$, is this correct?
- If yes, there are proof of the same "theorem" without the AOC?
- I've heard of a theorem which says that *if there exist a pair of injection $i_1,i_2, \ \ i_1:A \rightarrow B \ \ i_2:B \rightarrow A$ then there is a bijection $ f:A \rightarrow B$.* And that this theorem can be demonstrated without AOC, is this true? There is a similar theorem for surjective functions?

Comment: Pretty much all three questions has been asked before.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/659964/when-do-surjections-split-in-zf-two-surjections-imply-bijection/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(1,2) *As written*, the proof certainly seems to appeal to the axiom of choice for choosing each of the $x_y$s. But this is not necessary and easily eliminated: since you know that $A$ is countable, you can choose a bijection $A\leftrightarrow \mathbb N$ once and for all, and then for every $y$ let $x_y$ be the element in $F_y$ that has the smallest index.

(3) Yes, this is the [Cantor-Schröder-Bernstein theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%E2%80%93Bernstein_theorem), and it does not depend on the axiom of choice. The corresponding theorem for surjections [does require AC](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/176972/is-there-a-cantor-schroder-bernstein-statement-about-surjective-maps).

Comment: Thank you! In (1,2) isn't your argumentation the Axiom of Countable choice? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_countable_choice

Sorry if i'm silly, but i'm new to this kind of "set theory" and I'm very interested

Comment: @HaroldF: No, the axiom of countable choice allows you to choose one from each of countably many non-empty sets (but those sets can individually be as large or small as you want). That is different from what we need here -- namely, choosing a bijection $A\leftrightarrow \mathbb N$ gives us for free a way to choose an element of each of the _uncountably many_ nonempty subsets of $A$ (but each of _those_ subsets happens to be finite or countable).

Comment: We _can't_ appeal to countable choice instead here, because we need to make a choice for each element $y\in B$, and at this point we _don't know yet_ that there are only countably many $y$s.

Comment: Oh sorry, probably I expressed my self roughly. I mean, the fact that we can choose the lowest element in a subset of $\mathbb{N}$ for a family of subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ isn't again the AOC, or the AOCountableC?

Comment: @HaroldF: No, it's a basic property of $\mathbb N$ that every subset of it is either empty or has a (unique) smallest element. We can prove this by _mathematical induction_: Assume that $A\subseteq \mathbb N$  has no smallest element; then by induction on $n$ we have that $m\notin A$ for all $m\le n$ and in particular $n\notin A$. Therefore $A=\varnothing$.

Comment: Oh, ok now i see. Thank you again!