# Confused by one-to-one question, I think it's order incorrectly

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

I have this question and it seems a tad redundant

> If $A$ and $B$ are infinite sets, is it possible for there to be a 1-1 function from $A$ to $B$ and a 1-1 function from $B$ to $A$ without there being a 1-1 correspondence from $A$ to $B$?

Comment: No, see the Schroder-Bernstein Theorem.

Comment: What seems redundant?  The only word that can be deleted is "infinite".

Comment: You’ll find the Cantor-Schröder-Bernstein theorem [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%E2%80%93Bernstein_theorem), with more information [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/225576/intuition-behind-cantor-bernstein-schroeder).

Comment: $1-1$ correspondence is probably taken to mean something different from a $1-1$ function. It probably means a $1-1$ and onto function and/or a function with a left-and-right inverse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not a redundant question at all!
If I've understood you right, you want to know whether there could be an injection $A \rightarrow B$ and an injection $B \rightarrow A$ without there being a bijection between $A$ and $B$.

Actually, this is not possible.

There is a theorem called the Schröder–Bernstein theorem that states:
Whenever there is an injection $f:A \rightarrow B$ and an injection $g:B \rightarrow A$, then there exists a bijection $h:A \rightarrow B$.