# How to prove bijection from surjection

Tags: real-analysis

How to prove the following Lemma:
If there exists a function $f:B_1\to B$ that is surjective and $B_1 \subseteq B$, then there exists a bijective function between $B$ and $B_1$.

I am trying to prove Cantor–Bernstein theorem from this Lemma. I have already worked out how to prove the theorem assuming this Lemma is true. However, I have not got any clue on how to prove this Lemma yet:(

Before this Lemma I proved a theorem:
There is a function $f: X\to Y$ that is injective if and only if there exists a function $g: Y\to X$ that is surjective. I think this may be useful for the proof of this Lemma.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: I have already revised my question.

Comment: Do you see if $f:B_1\rightarrow B$ is surjective and $B_1\subseteq B$ then $B_1=B$?

Comment: That is what I am trying to prove. But how? And you should say $|B_1|=|B|$.

Comment: Let me give a brief sketch: On the contrary, we assume that $B_1\neq B$ i.e $B_1\subsetneq B$ then there exists an element in $B$ such that there is no pre-image of $B$. If there was a pre-image then $f$ would be a relation, not a function. This will give you a contradiction.

Comment: consider the example: $f: \mathbb{N}\setminus \{1\} \to \mathbb{N}$

Comment: This is a strange approach. The  Cantor-Schroeder-Bernstein theorem is provable combinatorially, without choice. The claim you are using needs the use of the axiom of choice, so you are employing more resources to prove something basic. Any proof will also be somewhat artificial, as you are trying to replace natural combinatorial ideas with others that are not really essential to the task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everyone seems a bit confused about what you are trying to do. You are trying to prove that lemma in order to prove Schroder-Cantor-Bernstein (SCB). I will demonstrate that there's no real way to do that, i.e. there is an effectively trivial reduction making SCB and your lemma equivalent. Thus any proof of this is effectively a proof of SCB, which is somewhat technical and challenging. E.g. see [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Schroeder-Bernstein_Theorem) for a proof. Since there is no (known) easy (by undergrad standards) proof of SCB, there is no such proof of your statement either. Thus you are effectively asking "how do I prove SCB?", for which you can see above or, since we like to keep things in-site, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/225576/intuition-behind-cantor-bernstein-schr%C3%B6der).

So why are these problems the same? For the sake of brevity, let's call your lemma L. Also for notation, write $C\cong D$ for there exists a bijection between $C$ and $D$. It is easy to verify $\cong$ is an equivalence relation.

Suppose we know L and we want to show SCB. Let $A, B$ sets with injections $f: A \to B$ and $g : B \to A$. Then clearly $B \cong g(B)$ (under the bijection of $g$ with restricted range). Then we have a bijection $h: g(B) \to B$, in particular a surjection. Also $f$ has a left inverse $k: B \to A$ (i.e. $k \circ f = id$) (for proof see [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Injection_iff_Left_Inverse)). Then $k$ is a surjection, as can be easily checked. Thus $k \circ h : g(B) \to A$, as a composition of surjections is a surjection. Thus we have a surjection $g(B) \to A$ so by your lemma, L, we have $g(B) \cong A$. Thus $A \cong B$. So we shown SCB.

Now suppose we know SCB. Let $A \subseteq B$ and suppose $f: A \to B$ is a surjection. Since [surjections have right inverses](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Surjection_iff_Right_Inverse) there is some $g: B \to A$ s.t. $f \circ g = id$. Thus $g$ is an injection. So we have an injection $B \to A$. But the inclusion map $i: A \to B$ just given by $i(x) = x$ is clearly and injection. Thus SCB applies and $A \cong B$. Thus we have shown your lemma, L.

Comment: Thanks for your reply anyway. In fact, I've already worked out the process you wrote SCB$\Leftrightarrow$this lemma. I am gonna to look at the proof you gave.

Comment: I disagree with some of these claims. There are very easy and intuitive proofs of the Cantor-Schroeder-Berenstein theorem. The other result needs the use of the axiom of choice in an essential way, so it is objectively less accessible.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a surjective map from $B$ to $A$, you can get an injective map from $A$ to $B$.  This requires Choice.  Just take an element of $f^{-1}(a)$ for each element of $A$.

Thus you can use Schröder-Bernstein.

Comment: I am trying to prove Schroder-Bernstein by using this lemma. But thanks for your reply anyway